# What does the dfx start error, with version mismatch and invalid cache for an older version of dfx, mean?

Tags: motoko

```
dfx start
Warning: The version of DFX used (0.9.3) is different than the version being run (0.13.1).
This might happen because your dfx.json specifies an older version, or DFX_VERSION is set in your environment.
We are forwarding the command line to the old version. To disable this warning, set the DFX_WARNING=-version_check environment variable.

Warning: The version of DFX used (0.9.3) is different than the version being run (0.13.1).
This might happen because your dfx.json specifies an older version, or DFX_VERSION is set in your environment.
We are forwarding the command line to the old version. To disable this warning, set the DFX_WARNING=-version_check environment variable.

Error when trying to forward to project dfx:
Invalid cache for version 0.9.3.
Installed executable: 0.13.1
```

I try many ways but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the "dfx.json" file and change the "dfx" version to whatever version you are currently working with. in your case it was changing the version from "0.9.3" to "0.13.1" .